# Converting long-math to work with doubles

Tags: double, rounding, long-integer, precision

If I have a calculation that is performed using `long` (64-bit integer) values with a final result that never exceeds 52 bits (the precision of a `double`-precision floating point), what is the best way to implement this calculation using `double` such that it always yields the same answer?

The difficulty comes in when performing, for example, a multiplication of two large numbers: If the `long` overflows, it drops the **highest** order bits, but if the `double` "overflows" (i.e. the result ends up with more than 52 significant bits), it drops the **lowest** order bits.

As an example, let's take the `next(...)` function in Java's `Random` class (edited a bit):

```java
protected int next(int bits) {
    seed = (seed * 0x5DEECE66DL + 0xBL) & ((1L << 48) - 1);  // seed is a long
    return (int) (seed >>> (48 - bits));
}
```

(Notice how the multiplication will likely overflow a `long`, but the result is ANDed down to 48 bits)

If I needed to exactly replicate the behavior of this function (or any other using `long`) in a language without the `long` data-type (e.g. JavaScript), what would be the most efficient way of doing this? [One of the GWT-implementations of this function](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/super/com/google/gwt/emul/java/util/Random.java?r=7414#322) splits the seed into two halves of 24 bits each to eliminate overflows (again edited a bit):

```java
double hi = seedhi * 0xECE66D + seedlo * 0x5DE;  // seedhi and seedlo are doubles
double lo = seedlo * 0xECE66D + 0xB;
double carry = Math.floor(lo >> 24);
hi += carry;
lo &= (1L << 24) - 1;
hi &= (1L << 24) - 1;

seedhi = hi;
seedlo = lo;
```

Is this the best one can do, or are there some tricks/hacks to make this more elegant?

Comment: Please do implement the necesssary tags. At least a [language-tag], and if not,then the numeric-datatype related tag!

Comment: @shekharsuman This question isn't really too language specific. Long integers and double-precision floating point numbers (and the described issue) exist in many languages. Java and JavaScript, while the ones I'm using, are just an example here. Not sure what you mean by "numeric-datatype". That tag doesn't seem to exist yet. Should I define it? If you can suggest a specific tag you'd like me to add, I'll gladly do so. Please accept my apologies if I wasted your time by having you read a question you don't care about...

Comment: There might be tricks specific to the thing you're trying to compute; e.g. algorithms concerned with eliminating the lowest bits of the result, rather than the highest bits.